# How to insert Records to SQL/Server from Access to SQL/Server using "Insert Into" with slow connection

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Here is what I tried.  WHAT ELSE HAVE I MISSED OR SHOULD HAVE TRIED?

My situation:

- SQL/Server in another country -
  direct Internet connection
  unreliable, private line
  cost-prohibitive, line condition changes constantly (ping 180 to 500+)
- Access SQL/Server via VPN connection - very slow but clean/reliable
- Access ACCDB (ace) database in US - low volume, working fine
- Need to "Insert into  select * from "

I have tried all of the following:

DAO - (currentdb.execute) runs Access SQL, OLEDB connection to remote SQL/Server across VPN -- can use "insert into" are very slow.

ADO using Access SQL - even slower.

OLEDB only, SQL command issued to remote SQL/Server can't see local ACCDB file, so you have to loop through recordset, built a SQL statement for each record.  Very slow.  Lots of extra coding.

OLEDB Access linked table to SQL/Server.  Fast to read data, very slow to insert records.

SQL/Server on both ends.  Local SQL/Server link tables to ACCDB and to remote server.  Works but does not improve speed.  1000 fairly small records take 5+ minutes to insert.

Bulk insert.  Can't do that, source data is not a text file, it's ACCDB. This isn't one-time conversion, it's a daily update of new/changed records.

SSIS -- seems fast as I am able to migrate the entire database rapidly, but doesn't look appropriate or easy for daily use of ordinary inserts and deletes.

HAVE NOT TRIED YET: SQL/Server subscriber-publisher mirroring/replication to keep remote tables "virtually" local.

So, suprisingly I found DAO to remote ACCDB (no SQL/Server) works 20x faster than SQL/Server through VPN.  But, I would much rather use SQL/Server.

WHAT ELSE HAVE I MISSED OR SHOULD HAVE TRIED?

Comment: I don't do this kind of thing, but there's a method to do execute DML in ADO that uses a batch mode. The problem with using ODBC is that it sends each record as an independent insert, so you need to force it into a batch mode insert, and so far as I'm aware, the ADO method is the only way. But I didn't post this as an answer because of the inordinate amount of hand-waving involved in what I'm suggesting! :)

Comment: Thanks for idea -- I started to look this up with the SqlBulkCopy Class.  Does anyone know how to do this in T-SQL or is it only ADO.NET?  I will do a separate post on that.

Answer (score 0):

Double check TCP/IP connections are enabled on the SQL Server & and are actually being used by the client (instead of named pipes) - if you use OLEDB stick `;Network Library=DBMSSOCN` on the end of the connection string to force this.

Have you tried "pulling" from the remote SQL server? i.e. your app calls a stored procedure that uses a OPENROWSET/OPENQUERY to pull data from a local SQL server? - useful on connections with asymmetric up/down speeds.

Comment: Interesting - thanks.  I am using SSMS to test.  TCP/IP and named pipes are enabled on remote server.  How do I force use with SSMS?

Re: Pulling -- the data to be pulled is in Access database, but ACCDB could be added as a linked server to local SQL/Server.  Would OpenRowSet query on remote see it?  I will try.

Comment: In SMSS It should be on the connection options tab after you click options on the logon dialog.
The prob with pulling from access (which is just a file not a server hosted application) is that it may have to pull the whole file over the network.

Comment: Thx. Maybe I don't understand how to insert recs across servers.

My SQL command runs on my local SQL server as "Insert into vpn.db.dbo.table (fieldlist) select (fieldlist) from openrowset('Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0','z:\myfile.accdb', mytable)

Where vpn is a linked server has the connection info, so I put tcp: in front of the IP address, shouldn't that force it?  No speed difference.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I will try the pull next; not exactly sure how but I think I need a linked server to Access db on local and run this query on remote: insert into remotetable (fieldlist) select (fieldlist) from openrowset(<linked-server-to-Access> on local>).  Do I have the right idea?

Comment: The pull would assume that I have access to the local server from the remote, like an IP address.  I am testing with local SQL/Express that can't be accessed from the remote, so I have to setup a different environment, correct?  Remote has to be able to connect to local.  Just having both servers in SSMS from local won't help.